# Differences between select statements

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

What is difference between select table; and select * from table; statements?

As I noticed sometimes select table gives a BP error that we must use field lists.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to MSDN there is no difference.

That said... adding the * should not be seen as a way to get rid of the BP warning.

When you need less than half of fields, it is always better to specify a field list. This is faster and it makes it easier for SQL Server to determine if an index can be used, and which index should be used.

*If a select statement is local to a method, use a field list to increase performance. If you use a select or a while select statement and the size of the fields that are used total less than 50 percent of the total record size, a warning appears if you do not use a field list.*

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa861766.aspx

Answer (score -1):

You didn't specify which DBMS you are using.

But as long as I know you for all DBMS you have to use  select * from table; and select table only will generate error.

However select table may be used in some of DBMS for simplicity but it is not a correct sql syntax.

Comment: I'm working on MS Dynamics Ax 2012.
select table returns all columns as select * from table;

Comment: The answer is in this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/aa656402.aspx
SelectStatement = select Parameters       


Parameters are [[ FindOptions ] [ FieldList from ]] TableBufferVariable [ IndexClause ] [ Options ] [ WhereClause ] [ JoinClause ]
Thus if use Find Options you have to use * from, if you didn't use find options then you are safe

find options are crossCompany | reverse | firstFast | [ firstOnly | firstOnly10 | firstOnly100 | firstOnly1000 ] | forUpdate | noFetch | [forcePlaceholders | forceLiterals] | forceselectorder | forceNestedLoop | repeatableRead | validTimeState